How do I relocate and possible extend the cabling for a ceiling light without having access to attic?
In the below picture the black spot in the wall (14' side) is a switch that controls the light (a small chandelier) that hangs of the ceiling off the center of the room (the ex owner had a dinner table there).
I need to relocate that light (the black spot at the end of the red arrow line) to the red dot in the below picture. I am not sure if the cable in the attic has any slack there, probably not.
I do not have access to attic  (or more exactly I am afraid to access it because I might crack the glaze of gypsum that was put on the ceiling to cover an old and ugly design. That probably added some 0.5-3/4" of mud to the ceiling. I would be probably stepping on joists and insulation but I would prefer not to if I have the option. I could use some large sheets of plywood to distribute my weight (tall heavy guy) but I would still avoid the hassle if I could.
I guess I would have two problems here:
-first find an acceptable solution to decom the old box and extend the cable to the new spot
-install a second box there -challenge with how to attach it to the joists or if there other options I would be curious what they are
The light I am installing looks like this one and its weight is 13 lb



The joist direction makes this a bit more difficult.  Best bet is doing it from the attic and using 4x4ft(or similar size) plywood/OSB/planks to carry your weight over a few joists/trusses.  I think you can place the box so it opens to the attic, instead of the ceiling.  You want your weight spread out, 150 pounds on one foot might move the joist a bit, but spread out over 16 sq ft is only about 10 pounds(probably less but not doing math).

Are you referring to the existing connection box? The electrical pannel is at the top right of the picture but one floor below (basement). I am assuming that the light is fed by a cable that reaches the wall switch firt. In theory from there it should to to light box. Since that switch is closer to a point that I can access I would try to disconnect the existing cable from there and replace it

The old light should be mounted to a junction box.  To extend the new cable from that box, is possible, but that box must not be hidden behind drywall/ceiling cover.  If you can add a new cable from the switch box to new light, go for it, then that old box can be hidden/removed(with wires disconnected/removed).   Usually much easier to use that old box as a junction box for new wire/light.

I am reading that it is against the code to leave a junction box behind the drywall

If used as a splice box, you can raise it up, so accessible from the attic.  If the wires are removed/disconnected/abandon you can hide it/remove it.  An in use box must be accessible from one surface without tools.  One side of a wall, one surface from the ceiling/attic.  A switch/receptacle box is only on one wall surface, but hidden from the other surface side of the wall.

An "old work" style junction box is installed from the finished room simply by cutting a hole in the drywall and inserting the box. The common style clamps to the drywall only but several brands offer a box with internal screws for fixing the box to wooden structure rather than drywall alone. One example is pictured below (photo: homedepot.com). It happens to be rated for fixtures up to 50 pounds so it'll manage your choice just fine.

NEC allows for electrical retrofit work (when the drywall is not cut open and cable is fished blindly through the structure) to skip the cable stapling that is normally required when installing NM-B cable.
You could cut the hole for the old work box in the new location, push new cable from the room into the attic through the existing box, and pull it through the hole at the new location. Much easier said than done, however. Fish rods can help.
You mention that there is an attic, it's just that you prefer not to enter it. If somebody is willing to go up there it'll make the wiring job much simpler. It'll also open the opportunity to delete the existing junction box: NEC requires that junctions remain accessible. If the attic can be accessed then a junction box can be placed there. Code doesn't require that junctions be in places you like entering! ;-)

So you are in agreement with what crip659 is saying above in the comments to my post, it is code compliant to leave the box above the ceiling but accessible from above. There will be some lose insulation around it.

@MiniMe I think buried in insulation would still count as accessible which is defined roughly as "can be reached without using tools or disassembling any portion of the building." But it's not very nice (for anybody in the future who may have need of finding it). I'd make the splice in a box mounted up higher, plainly visible above the insulation, instead.

It it probably attached to a joist...I can build a cassete that would stick out-of the insulation

This answer says it all. Make a hole and struggle. Eventually you will succeed or decide to go up there and do it the easy way. Fishing/pushing might be made much easier if you can stick your head up into the attic and see the top of this room, without actually walking up there. With a helper and a broomstick it will be a lot easier than fish tape through a 4-in hole.  Also with your head in the Attic, if the cable feeding the existing box is accessible anywhere, you can splice there cutting off the existing box then you can plaster over it. Your splice in a box screwed to a joist is allowed.

You can't decom the old junction box without attic access and a lot of luck with cable slack and joist positioning. You'll have to splice the new cable to the old cable in that junction box and put a cover on it and it must remain accessible. You'd have to cut your new light hole and fish the cable to the old box and enter the old box with the proper connector and make your connections. As far as mounting the new junction box, you'll either be under a joist so you could screw right into it or be in between two joists and use a box with the bar that connects to two joists. As a last resort, you could swag chain from the existing box to the new location or use cable molding.
You should really re-consider getting up into the attic. Get a small, lite electrician and pay them... you've done the whole house, take a break and have someone do this.

I am hoping that the light cable is comming from the switch toward the ceiling box. If that is the case I can disconnect from there and run a longer cable. That end is closer to a point in the ceiling where I would be able to physically get. From the attic. I just don't want to step over the wide span area of the living. Swag chaining is not esthetically pleasing.  In this case I can decom the old box.

@MiniMe  That will work.  I didn't mention that because you stated you didn't have access to the attic or was afraid to. It would also be easier to fish your cable from the new box to the switch.

@JACK the answer is, "it depends."  OP can decommission the old JB, as long as the location where the old wire is spliced is replaced with a new JB.  For example, the old JB is flush with the ceiling, and maybe the OP wants a JB that's sitting on top of a joist.

@Huesmann  On top of a joist without attic access, as stated by the OP, would  be difficult  even for a pro.  Access to the attic is a whole different solution.

You want to avoid "hassle".  Greg's answer along with, I think, my comment is the best way to avoid walking in the Attic. But either way will be a struggle and a lot of scratched up knuckles.  Laying some plywood off cuts across the joists is much less hassle than you think and will make the whole job a breeze.

@JACK the "access" issue here sounds more like fear than physical access...
